# Update chosen with on checked radios

Tags: jquery, jquery-chosen

I have en empty `select` which populates itself based on some radio buttons.

If a radio is checked, the select itself does get populated, but that is NOT reflected in the chosen plugin (the `chzn-drop` div remains empty).

I tried the following but to no avail:

```
$('.div-format :radio').each(function() {
    if ( this.checked ) {
        $('div.div-number select').trigger("chosen:updated");
    }
});
```

Comment: `$('.div-format radio')` should be `$('.div-format :radio')` or  a jsfiddle would be great.

Comment: changed, still not working

Comment: try trigger("change");

Comment: add the html elements to your question, no space between `$('.div-format:radio')`

Answer (score 0):

If you could change to this:

```
$('.div-format :radio').on('change', function() {
  if ( this.checked ) {
    $('div.div-number select').trigger("chosen:updated");
  }
});
```

---

You have to `trigger` it with `radio's` change event instead checking in loop on page load.

Comment: are the radios dynamically created through js.

Comment: No, but I do use a plugin to style them. HOWEVER, even if I switch off the radio buttons plugin, chosen still won't update.

Comment: @Jai also $(this).each() within change function

Comment: @c-link not its not needed as i see.

Comment: no errors and there is no reason for errors. The trouble is refreshing chosen, pure html elements work (the select itself does get updated).